# Is there a synopsis available for A Song of Ice and Fire?

Tags: george-r-r-martin, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

At some point in the indeterminate future, George RR Martin will release the next book in the *Song of Ice and Fire* series.

Considering that the last book was released so long ago, is there (or will there be) a synopsis of books 1-5 so readers won't have to re-read the previous books before reading the new one?

Comment: How detailed would that synopsis need to be? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Game_of_Thrones) has plot summaries.

Comment: Pretty detailed - there's a lot going on in the first 5 books !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Westeros.org](https://www.westeros.org/) offers [chapter by chapter summaries](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Chapters) for all currently published material including the main *A Song of Ice and Fire* novels, the released chapters of *The Winds of Winter*, and a couple ancillary works.

The site also offers deep dives into characters, history, geography and culture. It documents almost all of the interviews with George in the section ["So Spake Martin"](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/) as well.

It has been my main go-to when researching answers, to brush up on what has been going on in Westeros, and to remind myself what was show-only canon and what is book-only canon.